# vbscript to send GET request using IE error

Tags: windows, vbscript

I've got the vbscript below which needs to send a GET request and then logoff the current user. The idea is to replace the default "logoff" start menu item with this script.

When I run it with cscript it throws an error on line 9,

```
HTTPGet = IE.document.documentelement.outerhtml
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Maybe I should wait to receive the response before logging off the user, but as the line above doesn't seem to work I logoff immediately.

```
TOKEN = "xxxxx"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.visible = 0
IE.navigate "https://something.com/?action=create&token=" & TOKEN
Do While IE.Busy
   WScript.Sleep 200  ' see the above notice of change
   Exit Do                  ' prevents script host from going crazy waiting for IE
loop
HTTPGet = IE.document.documentelement.outerhtml
IE.quit
Set IE = Nothing

'WScript.Echo HTTPGet   'good for debugging. shows what you got back.

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -l"
```

If it matters this is for Windows XP only with IE 8.

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, knowing **which** error occurred really helps with troubleshooting an issue. That said, in your case the issue is probably that you exit from the `Do .. Loop` right away, so IE may not have finished loading the content you're trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.visible = 0
IE.navigate "https://host/?a=" & TOKEN
i = 1
Do While (IE.readyState <> 4)
   WScript.Sleep 1000  ' see the above notice of change
   i = i + 1
   If (i > 10) Then
      Exit Do
   End If
loop
HTTPGet = IE.document.documentElement.outerHTML
IE.Quit()
Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: How can I retrieve the HTTPGet variable before logging off the user?

Comment: HTTPGet variable will have page content - use it as string

Comment: Maybe is good idea (in this case) at line `HTTPGet = ...` to do `If Not IE.Busy Then HTTPGet = ...`